# Put the validation error text below input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, positioning

I don't really understand Javascript and I tried everything but can't find solution to my problem.

I'm using this plugin for validation, it works perfectly but just one small problem is that the error text it writes keeps displaying next to input field, I want it to show bellow the input field. Anyone can modify this script for that? Thank you very much :)

```
;(function($, window, document, undefined){

    // our plugin constructor
  var SimpleValidate = function(elem, options) {
    this.elem = elem;
    this.$elem = $(elem);
    this.options = options;
    this.metadata = this.$elem.data('plugin-options');
    this.$requiredInputs = this.$elem.find(':input.required');
  };

  // the plugin prototype
  SimpleValidate.prototype = {
    defaults: {
      errorClass: 'error',
      errorText: 'Please fill out this field.',
      emailErrorText: 'Please enter a valid E-mail',
      errorElement: 'strong',
      removeLabelChar: '*',
      inputErrorClass: 'input-error',
      completeCallback: '',
      ajaxRequest: false
    },

    init: function() {
      var self = this;

      // Introduce defaults that can be extended either
      // globally or using an object literal.
      self.config = $.extend({}, self.defaults, self.options, self.metadata);

      // What type of error message is it
      self.errorMsgType = self.config.errorText.search(/{label}/);
      self.emailErrorMsgType = self.config.emailErrorText.search(/{label}/);

      self.$elem.on('submit.simpleValidate', $.proxy(self.handleSubmit, self));

      return this;
    },

    checkField: function(index) {
      var self = this;
      var $field = self.$requiredInputs.eq(index);
      var fieldValue = $.trim($field.val());
      var labelText = $field.siblings('label').text().replace(self.config.removeLabelChar, '');
      var errorMsg = '';

      //Check if it's empty or an invalid email and format the error message
      if(fieldValue === '') {
        errorMsg = self.formatErrorMsg(self.config.errorText, labelText, self.errorMsgType);
        self.hasError = true;
      } else if($field.hasClass('email')) {
        if(!(/^([_a-z0-9-]+)(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@([a-z0-9-]+)(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$/.test(fieldValue.toLowerCase()))) {
          errorMsg = self.formatErrorMsg(self.config.emailErrorText, labelText, self.emailErrorMsgType);
          self.hasError = true;
        }
      }

      //If there is an error, display it
      if(errorMsg !== '') {
        $field.addClass(self.config.inputErrorClass).after('<' + self.config.errorElement + ' class="' + self.config.errorClass + '">' + errorMsg + '</' + self.config.errorElement + '>');
      }
    },

    formatErrorMsg: function(errorText, labelText, errorMsgType) {
      return (errorMsgType > -1 ) ? errorText.replace('{label}', labelText) : errorText;
    },

    handleSubmit: function(e) {
      var self = this;

      // We are just starting, so there are no errors yet
      this.hasError = false;

      // Reset existing displayed errors
      self.$elem.find(self.config.errorElement + '.' + self.config.errorClass).remove();
      self.$elem.find(':input.' + self.config.inputErrorClass).removeClass(self.config.inputErrorClass);

      // Check each field
      self.$requiredInputs.each($.proxy(self.checkField, self));

      // Don't submit the form if there are errors
      if(self.hasError) { 
        e.preventDefault();
      } else if(self.config.completeCallback !== '') { // If there is a callback
        self.config.completeCallback(self.$elem);

        // If AJAX request
        if(self.config.ajaxRequest) {
          e.preventDefault();
        }
      }
    }
  };

  SimpleValidate.defaults = SimpleValidate.prototype.defaults;

  $.fn.simpleValidate = function(options) {
    return this.each(function() {
      new SimpleValidate(this, options).init();
    });
  };

})( jQuery, window , document );
```

Comment: _"Anyone can modify this script for that?"_ Nop... Tell us what you've tried so far, why it didn't work, and attach a live example if possible, and you might get some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your CSS:

```
.error { display: block; }
```

Or change `ErrorElement` to `div`.

```
  new SimpleValidate(this, {errorElement: 'div'}).init();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're calling this, just pass in the parameter : `errorElement: 'p'`. The default is to use strong, which is an inline element.

Answer (score 0):

just replace

```
$field.addClass(self.config.inputErrorClass).after('<' + self.config.errorElement + ' class="' + self.config.errorClass + '">' + errorMsg + '</' + self.config.errorElement + '>')
```

with:

```
$field.addClass(self.config.inputErrorClass).after('<p><' + self.config.errorElement + ' class="' + self.config.errorClass + '">' + errorMsg + '</' + self.config.errorElement + '></p>')
```

Comment: One should be choosing the right errorElement, or setting the correct css style. Not changing the core functionality of the plugin.

Comment: Tried this and the css thing Robert suggested, both working :) Thanks a lot, you saved me :p

Comment: You are right Robert.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution might be to change `errorElement: 'strong'` to a [block element](http://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/HTML/Training), like `errorElement: 'p'`. You'll also want to make sure you [style the elements properly with CSS](http://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/CSS/Training).

If you'd like to learn JavaScript, I'd suggest taking a look at [Eloquent JavaScript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/contents.html).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I can not reproduce your code and therefore it is hard for me to say exactly what to do. However, it seems to me you should work around this piece of code:

```
$field.addClass(self.config.inputErrorClass).after('<' + self.config.errorElement + ' class="' + self.config.errorClass + '">' + errorMsg + '</' + self.config.errorElement + '>');
```

If I understood right, it adds the error message right after your input. Maybe you can use something like:

```
$field.addClass(self.config.inputErrorClass).after('<br>').after('<' + self.config.errorElement + ' class="' + self.config.errorClass + '">' + errorMsg + '</' + self.config.errorElement + '>');
```